# Use a variable for an Xpath query in Python

Tags: python, variables, xpath, expression

[N.B. I'm quite new to Python & Xpath]

I was wanting to perform an Xpath query and use a variable in the expression to cycle through all the elements using an index.

For example, rather than having the specific position of `[1]`, `[2]`, etc, I'd like to be able to place a variable `i` in this expression:

```
for x in root.xpath('/movies/a_movie[i]/studio'):
    print "<studio>" + x.text + "</studio>"
```

I'm unsure whether it's even possible, but I guess it can't hurt to ask!

To clarify, this is why I would like to do this: I'm trying to process all the elements of `a_movie[1]`, then at the end of the function, I want to process all the elements of `a_movie[2]`, and so on.

Comment: Just leave outh the `[i]` altogether? You are selecting `studio` elements that are inside of a `a_movie` element, you *already* would be looping over all matches..

Comment: @MartijnPieters I had that originally, but it didn't fit my needs – I'm trying to process all the elements of `a_movie[1]`, then at the end of the function, I wanted to process all the elements of `a_movie[2]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to loop over the `/movies/a_movie` tags instead, but only those that *have* a `studio` child:

```
for a_movie in root.xpath('/movies/a_movie[studio]'):
    name = a_movie.find('name').text
    studio = a_movie.find('studio')
    print "<studio>" + studio.text + "</studio>"
```

If you wanted to just print out the child elements of the `a_movie` element as XML, I'd just loop over the element (looping over the child elements) and use `ElementTree.tostring()` on each:

```
for a_movie in root.xpath('/movies/a_movie'):
    for elem in a_movie:
        print ElementTree.tostring(elem),
```

Comment: Thanks, Martijn. However, this still results in the issue I mentioned before; when I run my script, it prints all the child names successively – e.g. it printed all the studio names of each of the `a_movie` elements in the XML file at once.

I want it to print the children names of `a_movie[1]`, then all the children names of `a_movie[2]`, then `a_movie[3]`…

The reason I'd like to do this is to use the same block of code to process each of the `a_movie` elements.

Comment: @Daniel: This loops over the `a_movie` tags in order. If there are multiple `<studio>` tags inside each `a_movie` tag, then loop over those too. You didn't include a sample of your input XML, so I have to guess at what you mean here.

Comment: Here is the input XML: http://cl.ly/code/2N3F1g3L2W0V

I hope that helps clarify…

Comment: @Daniel: What is the problem then?  This code does what you want to do *already*. It loops over `a_movie` tags *in order*, then finds the `studio` tag inside. Inside the loop you *are* processing the `a_movie` tag. Added printing the movie name.

Comment: You must be misunderstanding my intention – here is the desired output:
`<title>The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring</title>
<rating>PG</rating>
<studio>New Line Cinema</studio>
<genre>Fantasy</genre>`

etcetera for each movie. In other words, I would like to reproduce the XML code how it currently appears.

Comment: @Daniel: And you are not able to do that yourself? If that was your desired output then your question was *not clear*, by a long shot.

Comment: Yes I can do it myself, but I was wanting to use an index so I can use the same block of code to process each movie, rather than copying and pasting the code for each movie. Yes sorry about that – I found it hard to describe, especially since I couldn't find anything resembling this query online…

Comment: @Daniel: This is what my code *does*: the loop body is *one block of code*, executed for each `a_movie` element.

Comment: Ok – for my reference, is there *no way* to do what I originally asked (to use an index variable)?

Comment: @Daniel: There is **no point** in using an index variable. You want to loop over the `a_movie` elements, this does that. To use a index instead, you'd be creating *inefficient*, and ugly code. It can be done with `for i in range(len(root.findall('.//a_movie'))): a_movie = root.find('.//a_movie[{}]'.format(i))` but that is approaching things back-to-front. That is *not* what the XPath positional selector is for.